# How to load a specific firefox profile using Selenium webdrivermanager?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I'm trying to use webdrivermanager library to load firefox driver in my selenium tests. I'm unable to load a specific firefox profile using this library. Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup() // To instantiate the firefox driver 

ProfilesIni Prof = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile profile = Prof.getProfile("C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\6xv9ndwh.SELENIUM");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But this instantiates a new driver and does not force the driver instantiated by firefoxdrivermanager to use the specific profile.

I tried using default gecko driver too that does not load the profile either. Here is the code that i'm trying:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile Profile = allProfiles.getProfile('default');

Profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

Profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(Profile);
```

Can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a new firefox profile 
steps for it are
1. Run this command  firefox.exe -p in run window

[image]

It will show this dialog box create profile with new name and exit the window.

After that perform this command in webdriver

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "Path to the exe of firefox driver");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("UrProfile Name which u created");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Hope it may help u...

Comment: I tried this but since i'm using Gradle, it creates 2 new instances of the driver and also it throws null pointer exception - Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (though not using webdrivermanager) for instantiating webdriver using Gradle:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
 capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
 driver = {new FirefoxDriver(capabilities)}
```